# Mutating UILabels in the ViewController from another unrelated class

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, tvos

I've been working on a score and highscore display for my tvOS sprite kit game. I have two classes. One of the classes is called "GameViewController," a UIViewController, and the other is a subclass of SKSpriteNode for my player. What I want to do is for every five updates, the score will update. The labels for the score and highscore are accessed via variables in my GameViewController class. In my Player class is where the updates are done, so I need to trigger a method in my GameViewController class *from* my Player class.

I've tried a few things. The furthest I've gotten is with this method using "Protocols" and "Delegates." I have a `protocol` class called "ScoreUpdateResponder" with a method:

`scoreUpdate(let score: Int)`

Thus, my GameViewController implements(? I'm a Java dev, trying to connect the dots here) the Responder class. So my cut-down class structure looks like this:

**Player Class:**

```
class Player: SKSpriteNode
{
    weak var responder: ScoreUpdateResponder?

    init(responder : ScoreUpdateResponder) 
    {
        self.responder = responder
    }

    let score = 0

    func update()
    {
      if(score % 5 == 0)
      {
        responder?.updateScore(score / 5)
      }

      score++;
    }
}
```

** ScoreUpdateResponder class**

```
protocol ScoreUpdateResponder : class
{
    func updateScore(let score: Int)

}
```

And then my **GameViewController** is:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, ScoreUpdateResponder
{
  func updateScore(score: Int)
  {
    scoreValue.text = String(score)

    if(score > Int.init(highscoreValue.text!)!)
    {
      highscoreValue.text = String(score)
    }
  }
}
```

I know I must be missing something. I suspect its with my initialization of the responder, or more generally in the Player class. Any help?

Comment: looks like you do not have your init setup correctly,  if there is code missing, use ... to let people know that there should be stuff there

Comment: are you doing super.init?  because right now you technically do not have an SKSpriteNode,  which makes me think that the init here is not even being called, so your responder is nil

Comment: I'm not sure how to set up the init. I tried to make one with the NSCoder parameter, but that made me need to initialize the player with the NSCoder parameter—something I don't want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make a few assumptions here.

**Assumptions**:

- There is only one player in this game, that's represented by a singleton
- Something not shown is responsible for calling player.Update()

I think the issue that you might be running into is the `let score = 0` line. I think what you're looking to do is actually: `var score = 0`. `let` effectively defines a constant.

I also edited some of the code to make it more inline with common swift style guides.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var scoreValue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var highscoreValue: UILabel!

    var player = Player()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        player.delegate = self
    }

    ...

}

// MARK: PlayerDelegate
extension GameViewController: PlayerDelegate {

    func playerDidUpdateScore(score: Int) {
        self.scoreValue.text = String(score)

        guard let highScoreText = highscoreValue.text, highScore = Int(highScoreText) where score > highScore else {
                return
        }

        self.highscoreValue.text = String(score)
    }
}

protocol PlayerDelegate {
    func playerDidUpdateScore(score: Int)
}

class Player: SKSpriteNode {

    var delegate: PlayerDelegate?
    static var score = 0

    func update() {
        if self.score % 5 == 0 {
            self.delegate?.playerDidUpdateScore(self.score / 5)
        }

        self.score++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll use this in future situations.